# Access fileds across Django related tables

Tags: django, django-models

If I  start access from class D such that I want to get all B.name and C.name given a matching 'a' inside D how do I go about it?  For example if D matches a name attribute in A then I want get all matching B.name(bs) and corresponding C.name for every B.name found.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    bs = models.ManyToManyField('B')

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    cs = models.ForeignKey('C')

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class D(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily get the result by

```
d = D.objects.get(id=5)
bs = d.a.bs.all()
#Now you can iterate over each bs and get their name
for b in bs:
  print(b.name, b.cs.name)
```

If you have lot of data, then this would produce multiple queries, so you should use [select related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to optimize queries.